# NodeJS: Unit Test for class calling constructor and functions of another class

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, rewire

I need to write an unit test for the following classA. I do not want to test methodA but set a dummy method instead:

```
const classB = require('classB');
function a() {
  const b = classB();
  b.methodA();
}
```

I tried to use rewire:

```
const classA = rewire('classA');
const classBMock = require('classB');
classBMock.prototype.methodA = function() {
}
classA.__set__('classB', classBMock);
classA.a();
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the way to go if you do want to test the code w/o changing. Alternatively you could make your code more unit testable by allowing dependency injection `function a(B = classB) { const b = new B(); ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right. Use the `rewire` package, set a mocked `classB` object. But it is not recommended to override the method on the prototype with a mocked one. You have to restore it to the original one after executing the test case. Otherwise, the `classB` with mocked `methodA` may cause other tests to fail.

The better way is to use dependency injection. Creating a mocked `classB` object for each test case and pass it into `a` function like this:

```js
function a(b) {
  b.methodA();
}

// test file
const b = { 
  methodA() {
    console.log('stubbed methodA');
  } 
}
a(b);
```

This can better ensure the isolation of test double between test cases.